# Getting Started with UnitTest++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, unittest++

This is the current code I have from their fundamental example: http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/UnitTest++.html

```
#include <unittest++/UnitTest++.h>

TEST(FailSpectacularly)
{
    CHECK(false);
}

int main() {
    return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
}
```

The include exists but I'm receiving errors: `undefined reference to UnitTest::Test::*` and `UnitTest::*` where `*` is some arbitrary class/method within the UnitTest++ library.

How can I get this to compile properly?

Comment: have you tried cppUnit ?

Comment: Same errors except it was `CppUnit::SourceLine()` and more that were `undefined reference`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.c%2B%2B.unittest%2B%2B.devel/13

Set the library path `-L/usr/include` and the library `-lunittest++`

Answer (score 2):

Mainly for my future reference but I sorted by linking to the library **last**.

```
g++ test.cpp -lunittest++
```