# First CppUnit Test: undefined reference to CppUnit::SourceLine::SourceLine

Tags: c++, unit-testing, compilation, include

I am trying to use the CppUnit test for the first time. When I try to compile the testing code I get:

> testing.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to
>   `CppUnit::SourceLine::SourceLine(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, int)'

And many other error messages.

I guess that the reason is that compiler does not know what UnitTest library is. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923538/getting-started-with-unittest) I found a person asking the same question. I try to use the recommendation from the answers of the linked questions but it still does not work. When I try `c++ -lunittest++ testing.cpp` I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunittest++
collect2: ld gives back 1 as End-Status
```

In the make files that are used by others and that work I see: `LDLIBS := -lcppunit`. So I tried `c++ -lcppunit++ testing.cpp` but I get the same error message as with the `-lunittest`.

Does anybody know how I can find location of the UnitTest library and pass this information to the compiler?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have managed to compile my code:

```
g++ testing.cpp -lcppunit
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Needed that `-lcppunit` argument. Still not sure how to generate a report though. I'm a newbie at this.

Answer (score 0):

I am compiling in netbeans.  I added the option -lcppunit in

Properties > Linker > Additional Options

and that let my test files compile and run.  Remember to not leave any spaces between options, as that will cause your code to fail to compile

Comment: Also add the option in the "Test Files" section.  Stupid netbeans.